# Why Does Range.Value = Left(....) not work?

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA, so this probably has a very simple answer!

I am trying to use the Left function to produce a string of the first digit of the cells in a column, but for reasons which I don't understand, when I use Range.Value = Left(...) it does not put the values that I have got from Left(...) into the cell.

I am left with a blank column A when the code has finished running.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and suggest how to fix it.

The code I wrote is:

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim var As Variant
r = Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For var = 2 To r
    Range("A" & var).Value = Left(Cells(var, 1).Text, 1)
Next var
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: `Range("B1").CurrentRegion` ... do you have values in A or are they in B? If so you will need `Cells(var, 2)`. As it stands your code is circular as both sides refer to the same cell.

Comment: Thanks. That was it!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are not declaring something completely - either the worksheet, or the rows in the current region. Start with something as simple as this one to see how it works:

```
Public Sub HereComesTheCode()

    Dim r As Long: r = 10
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = Worksheets(1)

    For i = 2 To r
        With wks
            .Range("A" & i) = Left(.Cells(i, 1), 1)
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be an alternative method, scanning the cells in B and writing the first letter of each cell into the cell to the left of it:

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("B1", "B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
    c.Offset(0, -1).Value = Left(c.Text, 1)
Next
```

Note: Strictly speaking, it would be good practice to qualify your ranges though:

```
Dim c As Range
With Worksheets("YOUR_SHEET_NAME_HERE")
For Each c In .Range("B1", "B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
    c.Offset(0, -1).Value = Left(c.Text, 1)
Next
End With
```